# Windows 10 is suspending a process started by batch file/command prompt

Tags: windows-10, command-line, suspend

I have a command I'd like to run, which contains an executable and then a number of arguments. The executable in this case is Unreal Engine.

The command that I am wanting to run is something along these lines:

```
"C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.19\Engine\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor.exe" "C:\Users\me\path\to\project\project.uproject"
```

If I create a shortcut to UE4Editor.exe and change it to include the argument, everything works fine.

However, if I put the above command into a .bat file, or run it on the Command Prompt (or PowerShell, or through Python), it gets part way through loading and then Suspends the Unreal Engine process.

This is what I see in Task Manager when it has suspended:

[image: Suspended Task]

Any idea what could be causing this? Unreal Engine gives me a "loading" screen which gets to about 45% before it is suspended.

As previously mentioned, if I start the same command through a Shortcut, it starts fine.

Thanks

Comment: I found a tool called pssuspend (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pssuspend) which I can use to resume the tasks, but that's obviously not a decent solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do, get [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and run it only filtering for `Process and thread activity` Second icon from the right.

Now start `UE4Editor.exe` through a shortcut and the command line and then compare the two, look at the details for `Process Create` and `Process Start` operations and subsequent loading of DLLs, maybe it gives you a clue on what is different and how to could start it say from `Start-Process` in PowerShell to make it work the same way it does from the shortcut.